# Junk Characters in excel

Tags: data-export, csv, excel

I exported my client's data as .csv file but when i open it in excel then it will show junk characters for Blank spaces after any character like below

[image: Error while opening csv in WPS office]

but in csv file blank spaces treat same as blank space

[image: Correct encoding in csv]

so is there any way to remove these junk characters or setting an encoding for csv file?

Comment: How did you export the data to the csv files?

Answer (score 1):

As a general recommendation, use the free, open-source LibreOffice Calc to process CSV files. Unlike Excel, it correctly handles Unicode text and allows you to select the CSV file's encoding when you open the file.

Excel, while it has many faults, doesn't render spaces as accented characters at random. Your file appears to contain either (a) Unicode-encoded blank characters or (b) binary nonsense data, which your text editor is showing as blank and Excel is interpreting in some encoding of its choice (probably Codepage 1252).

Answer (score 0):

Try not to just double click on the .csv file. Instead open up Excel.

Then click on the Data Tab and then click on From Text (pictured below)

[image: Data Import Tab]

Then in the file open menu select your .csv/.txt file.

This will now give you a section (pictured below) to select the type of encoding your file is using (pictured below). Follow the rest of the wizard to have your data imported into your spreadsheet.

[image: Text Import Wizard]